# Images occasionally won't show

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

This is one of those random things without any errors to report about :/

From time to time images don't show in our app. There's no sign of any errors. Our app shows a list of user submitted images and there's a lot of them.

Here's some info:
- jpg images @ 180x180
- images are pulled from our backend
- and a few images are pulled from googles static map service
- it happens on iOS and Android
- it happens randomly
- no errors show up in the console
- an restart of the app will fix it
- I've experienced it both with SDK 4.1 and SDK 5.1
- it's an Alloy app

Has anyone seen anything similar to this? I know there's no code examples but I don't know where to look as nothing fails and I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue relates to [Appcerator - Android 6 image don't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315532/appcerator-android-6-image-dont-load), it has already been fixed yesterday and will be part of the upcoming SDK release 5.2.0.

Comment: I don't think so. I see this issue on both iOS and Android regardless of SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to show a bunch of images at the same time? And some of them fail to load?

If you are using ImageView, I would just listen to the `error` event and reload the image. [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-error)

Comment: Yes i'm trying to show a lot of images, but all external images fail. Only bundled images are shown. Refreshing the view dosn't help, only a restart of the app does.

It's as if theres some adblocker/firewall suddenly blocking all images in the app. They just don't show.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but sometimes when I set an image directly by url to an ImageView, the imagem did't appear or was't the most current, so I've added:

```
$.ImageView.image = 'http://example.com/image.jpg?'+Math.random()
```

Returns something like this:

```
$.ImageView.image = 'http://example.com/image.jpg?0.6108739504124969'
```

Comment: A cachebuster is not the solution. I thinking more in the lines of something deep within the SDK.