# Appcerator - Android 6 image don't load

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

External images don't load in image view in Android 6, using de sdk 5.1.2GA
Any tip ?

This error in console:
Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException

```
$.img.image = "http://matematicazup.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/prof-marcelo-ferbat-perfil-300.png";
```

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the Appcelerator JIRA https://jira.appcelerator.org/. If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a JIRA-ticket regarding this issue (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19899) which has been resolved. The fix is included in Titanium SDK 5.2.0+. Thanks!